# Insert _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, view

Is that possible to use viewstart only for a particular controller and view?
I was using only _Layou.cshtml file inside views folder.
Now i added _ViewStart.cshtml as common view inside views folder and moved _Layout to Shared folder.

This is program structure:

```
Homecontroller
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

Index.cshtml
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}

_Layout.cshtml
{
//design code for Index.chtml
}
```

as per the above code, _Layout rendered for homecontroller .
When done the changes mentioned at the very first line, I'm getting the controls inside _Layout.cshtml in every controller I use.
I use nearly 6 controllers.
How to make this change without disturbing the entire code.
Please help.

PS: I need to introduce _ViewStart into the program since I'm integrating openid with my already developed project.

Comment: `_ViewStart.cshtml` is meant, by convention, to be used within the entire area. If you want it to not apply to certain views/controllers, you will have to place them in different area(s). In your case, it sounds like you'd be better off making different layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can create another `_ViewStart.cshtml` (in `Views/[controller]` a sub-folder for example) that will override the root one, something like:

   `@{ Layout = null; }`
2. You can simply use the `ViewBag` to determine whether to use Layout or not:

   > ```
   > public ActionResult AnotherAction()
   > {
   >      ....
   >      ViewBag.NoLayout = true;
   >
   >      return View();
   > }
   > ```

   and in your `_ViewStart`:

   > ```
   > @{
   > if (ViewBag.NoLayout == null || !ViewBag.NoLayout)
   >      Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
   > }
   > ```

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about `MVC3 Razor layouts` on Scott Guthrie's [Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)

Comment: It would be a good idea to give the reason _why_ he would want to read more on layouts. That would be a more solid SO answer and help anyone in the future that stumbles across this question.

Comment: @jesus.tesh agree with you but better to read Scott Guthrie there are more useful things to read.